# Ruby: Default values for define?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question about define my main issue is I am a bit confused on how the parameters work for it.

This is my Methods

```
 def repeat(repeated_word)
    @repeated_word = repeated_word
    "#@repeated_word #@repeated_word"
    end
```

This is my rspec test to make sure my method works.

```
 describe "repeat" do
    it "should repeat" do
      repeat("hello").should == "hello hello"
    end

    # Wait a second! How can you make the "repeat" method
    # take one *or* two arguments?
    #
    # Hint: *default values*
    it "should repeat a number of times" do
      repeat("hello", 3).should == "hello hello hello"
    end
   end
```

it passes the first test but fails the second. My confusion is if i add a second parameter meaning def repeat(repeat_word, times_repeated)
the first test then fails because it has the wrong number of arguments. Not sure how to set up default values?

Answer (score 1):

```
def repeat(repeated_word, repeats=2)
  repeats.times.map { repeated_word }.join(' ')
end
```